# On mouseover how to highlight an object's point so that I can draw connector from highlighted point

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I want to develop similar features as in  http://www.cacoo.com for connector.Please somebody help me its urjent.

Comment: should I use any library for this.If any suggest me the correct one.